# Debugging array related error (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I was working to implement the [rod cutting problem](https://youtu.be/ElFrskby_7M) and I encountered this error:

```
a.out: malloc.c:2392: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The dashed comment block is where I suspect the error is coming from, but I'm not sure why. Trying to run under gdb I am having hard time pin-pointing it (seems to be crashing at i = 7) (compiling using: g++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int max_from(int * arr, int n)
{
    int maxval = arr[1];
    for(size_t i = 2; i < n; ++i)
        if(arr[i] > maxval) maxval = arr[i];

    return maxval;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 11;

    int * V = new int[n]; // given arr, price at(i)
    int * C = new int[n]; // optimal at length(i)

    V[0] = 0; // non-affecting value, using 1 as starting point

    V[1] = 1;
    V[2] = 5;
    V[3] = 8;
    V[4] = 9;
    V[5] = 10;
    V[6] = 17;
    V[7] = 17;
    V[8] = 20;
    V[9] = 24;
    V[10] = 30;

    C[0] = 0;

    // --------------------------------------------------

    for(size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int * arr = new int[i];
        for(size_t k = 1; k <= i; ++k)
        {
            arr[k] = V[k] + C[i-k];
        }

        C[i] = max_from(arr, n);

        delete [ ] arr;
    }

    cout << max_from(C, n) << '\n'; // maximized cost
    // --------------------------------------------------

    delete [ ] V;
    delete [ ] C;
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand why people use new/delete nowdays..

Comment: @ikh Yeah, I should avoid it, but since I'm juggling a few different programming language and framework at the moment and because above code is just to internalize the concept being implemented, I went with the first thing I remembered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int* arr = new int[i];
for(size_t k = 1; k <= i; ++k)
    arr[k] ....
```

Here is out-of-bound error. Shouldn't it be `new int[i + 1]`?

Also, I highly recommend you **never** to use raw new/free. `std::vector` is the right thing for this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is in

```
    C[i] = max_from(arr, n);
```

in the for loop in `main()`.

Observe that `arr` is allocated of dimension `i`

```
    int * arr = new int[i];
```

where `i` start from `1`.

But in `max_from(arr, n)`, `arr` is used at position `i` where `i` start from `2` and end to `n-1`.

So, for the first loop, when the `i` in the main loop is `1`, `arr` is allocated of size `1` but is accessed at position `10`.

Crash!

p.s.: well... but ikh is right too.